# Join and get queryset accordring to many to many field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have MyUser model with ForeignKey and ManyToMany related fields city and skills:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField()
    skills = models.ManyToManyField('jobs.Skill')

class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

suppose this my table data in database:

```
{'email': 'some@email.com',  'skills': ['Python', 'Java']},
{'email': 'another@email.com',  'skills': ['JavaScript', 'C#', 'Python']}
```

```
>>> MyUser.objects.all().count()
```

output is 2 but I want:

```
MyUser.objects. ..........
```

answer to 5 my like following data:

```
{'email': 'some@email.com', 'city': 'London', 'skills': 'Python'},
{'email': 'some@email.com', 'city': 'London', 'skills': 'Java'},
{'email': 'another@email.com', 'city': 'Berlin', 'skills': 'JavaScript'},
{'email': 'another@email.com', 'city': 'Berlin', 'skills': 'C#'},
{'email': 'another@email.com', 'city': 'Berlin', 'skills': 'Python'},
```

Comment: Is there any `city` field in `MyUser` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply query like this:

```
MyUser.objects.values('email', 'city', 'skills__name')
```

You can also rename the `skills__name` field like this:

```
MyUser.objects.annotate(skill=F('skills__name')).values('email', 'city', 'skill')
```

Comment: how can i remove one data from this queryset? –

Comment: You can limit the information via `values(<parameters>)`.

Comment: i meen from queryset, exclude(skill='C#') remove last 3 data, with same email

Comment: it should work, or exclude(skills__name='C#')

Comment: i tried but it delete all data with same email. it mean this is removing a object

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`annoate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate), with Count aggregation and [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) to get the desired output so:

```py
from django.db.models import Count

all_users = MyUser.objects.annotate(num_skills=Count('skills')).values('email', 'num_skills')

data = []
for single_user in all_users:
    email = single_user['email']
    num_skills = single_user['num_skills']
    skills = MyUser.objects.get(email=email).skills.all()
    for skill in skills:
        data.append({'email': email, 'city': 'London', 'skills': skill.name})

print(data)
```

Obviously, not a good solution as `city` value is hardcoded to `London` and `Berlin` for the first and second user respectively.

Comment: how can i remove one data from this queryset?